# Prevent nano from keeping history of searches

Tags: files, configuration, customization, nano

I recently noticed that when searching for a String in a file using `nano`, that the search gets saved to this file:

```
~/.nano_history
```

But this is not necessary, and I don't want this feature, so is there any way to disable it so that it does not write the search history to a file?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

**Package Information:**

```
nano:
  Installed: 2.2.6-3
  Candidate: 2.2.6-3
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.6-3 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file `/etc/nanorc` (run `sudo nano /etc/nanorc`) and comment out the line `set historylog` in this section:

```
## Enable ~/.nano_history for saving and reading search/replace strings.
set historylog
```

Which should then look like this:

```
## Enable ~/.nano_history for saving and reading search/replace strings.
# set historylog
```

Then exit&save and you're done!

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way could be to clear the file, then set read-only permissions to that file with:

```
echo "" > ~/.nano_history
chmod 400 ~/.nano_history
```